# Laravel, tailwind and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack, tailwind-css

I am trying to to install tailwindcss to laravel 8 project and then install Vue. After struggling for a while I realized that installing breeze would install the authentication features together with the tailwindcss. It's working fine. Now the problem is that when I install Vue(npm install vue) and try to compile the assets (npm run dev), I am getting an error, "Proper vue loader is not found" . How can I solve this?

[image: 1]

Comment: you need install `vue-loader`

Comment: After installing the vue-loader and adding vue() method on mix.js('resources/js/app.js',  'public/js').vue() on webpack.mix.js file it worked. Thanks